# Is identifying integer literals in decimal, octal, and hexadecimal notation the same in escape characters?

Tags: c++

Going through the 5th edition of the *C++ Primer* book I was told that integers literals that begin with `0` are interpreted as `octal`. It left me with this example on how the integer literal `20` is represented in the following notations:

```
 20 `/* decimal */` 024 `/* octal */` 0x14 `/* hexadecimal */`
```

Advancing a couple of pages, I was then introduced to escape characters and how to represent numerical values of characters with them using `octal` and `hexadecimal` digits. I was then presented with this...

```
std::cout << "Hi \x4dO\115!\n"; // prints Hi MOM! followed by a newline
std::cout << '\115' << '\n'; // prints M followed by a newline
```

> *Note that if a `\` is followed by more than three `octal` digits, only the first three are associated with the `\`. For example, `\1234`
>   represents two characters: the character represented by the `octal`
>   value `123` and the character `4`. In contrast, `\x` uses up all the hex
>   digits following it; `\x1234` represents a single, 16-bit character
>   composed from the bits corresponding to these four `hexadecimal` digits.
>   Because most machines have 8-bit chars, such values are unlikely to be
>   useful. Ordinarily, `hexadecimal` characters with more than 8 bits are
>   used with extended characters sets using one of the prefixes from
>   **Table 2.2**.*

Ok so is it that `decimal` isn't used with escape characters when representing the numerical value of chars, or the whole interpretation of what is defined as a `octal` is changed with escape characters ? I'm confused because I thought `octals` are interpreted as literals that begin with `0` if it isn't followed by an `x`, but what I'm reading from that previous block quote...

> For example, `\1234` represents two characters: the character
>   represented by the `octal` value `123` and the character `4`.

It says the **octal value** `123`, but there is no `0`. So is it only with escape characters that they truncate the zero, and if so then how is a `decimal` literal represented when using escape characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says the **octal value** 123, but there is no 0. So is it only with escape characters that they truncate the zero, and if so then how is a decimal literal represented when using escape characters ?

That is correct - you do not need zero to have an octal escape sequence. The grammar is defined in [lex.ccon] as:

```
octal-escape-sequence:
    \ octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit

hexadecimal-escape-sequence:
    \ hexadecimal-digit
    hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
```

Or alternatively:

> The escape `\ooo` consists of the backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits that are taken to specify
>   the value of the desired character. The escape `\xhhh` consists of the backslash followed by x followed by one
>   or more hexadecimal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. There is no limit to
>   the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence. A sequence of octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by
>   the first character that is not an octal digit or a hexadecimal digit, respectively. The value of a character
>   literal is implementation-defined if it falls outside of the implementation-defined range defined for `char` (for
>   literals with no prefix) or `wchar_t` (for literals prefixed by L).

So `\19` would be an octal literal with value 1 followed by a decimal literal with value 9. There is no decimal escape sequence. The full table of possibilities is enumerated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 2):

An octal literal needs to start with a `0`.  This is what tells the compiler that we are using a octal number.  When using the escape character the number(s) after it are treated as an octal number and it does not need to be prefixed with a `0` as the compiler know it is an octal number.  This is why `\x` is needed if you want to use a hex number.

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) has a good table showing all of the [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 2):

Characters can be defined using the following escape sequences.

From the C++11 Standard:

**2.14.3 Character literals**

> ```
> simple-escape-sequence: one of
> \’ \" \? \\
> \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
>
> octal-escape-sequence:
> \ octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
>
> hexadecimal-escape-sequence:
> \x hexadecimal-digit
> hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
> ```

A string literal can use any of the escape sequences used to define character literals.

Coming to your question ...

> Ok so is it that decimal isn't used with escape characters when representing the numerical value of chars,

The answer is "Yes". Decimals cannot be used to define escape sequences of character literals or characters in string literals.

> I'm confused because I thought octals are interpreted as literals that begin with 0 if it isn't followed by an x,

That is true only for integer literals, not when being used as escape sequences for character literals and characters in string literals.